# How to convert dictionary with list of unequal size and elements to Dataframe with 1 and 0 values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `python 3.7.6`

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
key   - string
value - list of strings
```

**the values (lists) are not in same size**.

for example:

```
 {'GP': ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4'], 
 'MIN': ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4'],
 'PTS': ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4'], 
 'FGM': ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_4'], 
 'FGA': ['col_2'], 
 'FG%': ['col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4'],
 '3P Made': ['col_2', 'col_3'], 
 'AST': ['col_2', 'col_3'], 
 'STL': ['col_2'], 
 'BLK': ['col_2', 'col_3'],
 'TOV': ['col_3']}
```

I want to convert this dictionary to `Dataframe`, where the key is the row and columns are the list values, and the content is 1 or 0 (depends if the row has the list values or not):

```
            col_1       col_2       col_3    col_4  
 GP           1         1           1           1
 MIN          1         1           1           1 
 PTS          1         1           1           1 
 FGM          1         1           0           1 
 FGA          0         1           0           0 
 FG%          0         1           1           1
 3P Made      0         1           1           0
 AST          0         1           1           0
 STL          0         1           0           0
 BLK          0         1           1           0
 TOV          0         0           1           0
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) with `d.keys()` and `d.values()` of dictionary:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(d.values()), index=d.keys(),columns=mlb.classes_)
print (df)
         col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
GP           1      1      1      1
MIN          1      1      1      1
PTS          1      1      1      1
FGM          1      1      0      1
FGA          0      1      0      0
FG%          0      1      1      1
3P Made      0      1      1      0
AST          0      1      1      0
STL          0      1      0      0
BLK          0      1      1      0
TOV          0      0      1      0
```

Pandas only solution, but slowier with `Series`, [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) and [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = pd.Series(d).str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a series, `explode` it, and then use `get_dummies` with `sum`:

```
pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(d).explode()).sum(level=0)
```

Or you can play with the exploded series and `unstack`:

```
(pd.Series(d).explode()
   .to_frame(name='cols')
   .assign(values=1)
   .set_index('cols', append=True)['values']
   .unstack('cols', fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
         col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
GP           1      1      1      1
MIN          1      1      1      1
PTS          1      1      1      1
FGM          1      1      0      1
FGA          0      1      0      0
FG%          0      1      1      1
3P Made      0      1      1      0
AST          0      1      1      0
STL          0      1      0      0
BLK          0      1      1      0
TOV          0      0      1      0
```